# Stop iframe from reloading on hover

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to stop iframes from re-loading on hover...

```
onmouseover="javascript:if(loadintoIframe) {loadintoIframe('Supportfrm', 'http://mysite.com/page.php); loadintoIframe=null;}"

onmouseover="javascript:if(loadintoIframe) {loadintoIframe('TroubleshootingFrm', 'http://mysite.com/page.php); loadintoIframe=null;}"
```

loadintoIframe=null; works for one iframe on load but not both. Got a feeling null negates the option for hovering over a second.

Comment: if you are loading frame from third party site, then you cannot get href, so answers below may not work. 

you need to add an onload event to iframe to check if its loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use two different functions with flags you can set indicating the form was loaded?

```
<script>
    var supportFormIsLoaded = false;
    var troubleShootingFormIsLoaded = false;

    function loadSupportForm() {
        if(supportFormIsLoaded) return;

        loadintoIframe('Supportfrm', 'http://mysite.com/page.php');
        supportFormIsLoaded = true;
    }
    function loadTroubleShootingFForm() {
        if(troubleShootingFormIsLoaded ) return;

        loadintoIframe('TroubleshootingFrm', 'http://mysite.com/page.php');
        troubleShootingFormIsLoaded = true;
    }
<script>
```

and then the mouse overs:

```
onmouseover="loadSupportForm()"

onmouseover="loadTroubleShootingFForm();"
```

Comment: Or, better yet, unregister the mouseover event after loadintoIframe is called using `this.onmouseover= null;`

Answer (score 1):

So when you hover over an iFrame it loads in a link? Why not check the previous link to see if it's the new link before setting it.

```
if(this.href='http://mysite.com/page.php') 
    loadintoIframe('Supportfrm', 'http://mysite.com/page.php');
```

Something similar. Also, you're missing quotes at the end of your URL.

Comment: because I'm using a script from dynamicdrive<br/>

[1]http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm)<br/>

Script auto resizes iframe (which works find). Trying to find a way to do this from link event attribute so I don't have to chop their script up. <br/>

If I don't add loadintoIframe=null to each link; both iframes load on hover just fine. They just keep reloading if hovered over again.

Comment: You could always store iFrames that have been loaded into an array and only load it if it's not been loaded yet by checking if it's in the array?